# why is the name `loop` treated differently in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, reserved-word

I issue the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
loopa INTEGER,
loop  INTEGER
);
```

Then, examining the DDL in the server (using a client-side tool like [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) - sorry don't know the query to produce it directly) I see the following:

```
CREATE TABLE
    foo
    (
        loopa INTEGER,
        LOOP INTEGER
    );
```

Observe the change in case for the column named `loop` but not for the one named `loopa`. Looking at the list of [SQL keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `loop` doesn't appear to be a keyword. Why then, this selective change?

This *seems* to be related to a problem I am having with a trigger trying to access a column `loop` in a table where I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: record "new" has no field "loop"
```

(where I get the same error regardless of whether the code in the trigger function access the field as `NEW.LOOP` or `NEW.loop`)

***UPDATE***

The upper-casing *seems* to be an artifact of DbVisualizer. `psql` shows:

```
psql (9.1.13)
Type "help" for help.

foo-test=> \dS+ foo
                    Table "test.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------
 loopa  | integer |           | plain   | 
 loop   | integer |           | plain   | 
Has OIDs: no
```

Yet this still doesn't explain why the PostgreSQL engine apparently doesn't allow my trigger to access `NEW.loop`. When I rename the column (and the trigger code) to `loopi` everything appears to work fine. So, there is likely something deeper at work here than just a DbVisualizer glitch. I'll try to create a SSCCE later.

***UPDATE 2***

A SSCCE for the trigger problem has been created [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76776/34332).

Comment: The issue is with DbVisualizer, not Postgres.

Comment: @ypercube: I've updated the post.

Comment: Probably DbVis created the table with the column quoted: `"LOOP"`. As a result, if you do that, you then have to always quote the column. `loop` or `LOOP` will not work, the column has to be referred as `"LOOP"`.

Comment: @ypercube I used `psql` to create the table, I use DbVisualizer only to view the DDL on the server side. Even if I had used DbVisualizer, the column is not "LOOP" as attested by the output of `psql`.

Comment: Both the table and the trigger were created with psql?

Comment: @ypercube: created SSCCE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76776/34332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word LOOP is a reserved word in PL/pgSQL.  If you want to use it as a column name, you need to quote it.

Comment: You should add that the quoting is only needed within PL/pgSQL, not for plain SQL.

Comment: I was checking for reserved words in this list: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html. Is there a list of PL/pgSQL keywords posted somewhere? Google reveals discussions and even source code: http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3223/doxygen-postgres9.3.2/html/de/dcb/pl__scanner_8c_source.html but not a readable list.