# trigger can't access column loop

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, reserved-word

SSCCE:
The following script:

```
$ cat test.sql 
CREATE TABLE public.foo (
loop INTEGER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo_fun(loop INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
    SELECT TRUE;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo_tr_fun() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    fRV BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    SELECT public.foo_fun(NEW.loop) INTO fRV;
IF fRV THEN
    RETURN NEW;
ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'bar';
END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_tr AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.foo
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.foo_tr_fun();
```

... which I run with:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --quiet -X -U some-user -d some-db -f test.sql
```

... when I then try to insert a row into `foo` (from `psql`):

```
$ psql -U some-user some-db
psql (9.1.14)
Type "help" for help.

RegTAP=> SELECT * FROM public.foo;
 loop 
------
(0 rows)

RegTAP=> INSERT INTO public.foo(loop) VALUES(0);
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "loop"
LINE 1: SELECT public.foo_fun(NEW.loop)
                              ^
QUERY:  SELECT public.foo_fun(NEW.loop)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "foo_tr_fun" line 5 at SQL statement
RegTAP=>
```

Comment: Have you tried the same with quoting the reserved word `loop` inside plpgsql? In lower case: `"loop"`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I confirm that when `loop` is quoted in the plpgsql code, it works.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That works. But why? Is `loop` reserved in pg/SQL?

Comment: @ypercube: I don't think that's how it *should* be, since the column name is table qualified (`NEW.loop`) and should be unambiguous that way, but obviously the parser is confused if the keyword `loop` is used as unquoted identifier. That aside, it's generally a bad idea to use key words as identifiers ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Have you got a link with pgSQL keywords? Because `LOOP` is not in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: @ypercube: It's "plpgsql" or "PL/pgSQL". The link you quote just lists *SQL* keywords. I don't know of a comprehensive list for plpgsql. BTW, the situation in Postgres 9.3 is unchanged: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/857f3/1 . I did not see any news on this for 9.4 either. I really think this needs some attention ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the **key word** `loop` needs to be **double-quoted** inside PL/pgSQL or the parser is confused:

```
SELECT public.foo_fun(NEW."loop") INTO fRV;
```

The situation in Postgres 9.3 is unchanged:
[SQL fiddle with quotes (works).](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/707c7/1)
[SQL fiddle without quotes (doesn't work).](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/857f3/1)

It's generally a good idea to avoid typical key words like `loop` as identifiers. There are some plpgsql key words in addition to [SQL key words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (like for procedural elements or exception handling), but I don't know of a comprehensive list of additional plpgsql key words. The source code would be my best idea.

I found a [related discussion on pgsql-hackers](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/23085.1194285255@sss.pgh.pa.us#23085.1194285255@sss.pgh.pa.us) from 2007. It seems the matter is not fully resolved, yet.
Didn't see any changes here for Postgres 9.4 either ...